# Unsafe to delete items from DB_File tied hash while iterating with `each`?

Tags: perl, each, netbsd, tie

### The Problem

I'm using NetBSD 6.1, Perl v5.18.1, and DB_File v1.818.  If I iterate over a DB_File-tied hash using `each` and delete each item from the hash, not all items are deleted.  Here is a script demonstrating the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DB_File;

my $dbfile = "/tmp/foo.db";
! -f $dbfile or unlink($dbfile) or die("unable to delete $dbfile");

my %db;
tie(%db, "DB_File", "/tmp/foo.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);

# add some random records
my @chars = ("0".."9", "a".."f");
for (1..10) {
    my ($key, $val);
    $key .= $chars[rand(@chars)] for 1..10;
    $val .= $chars[rand(@chars)] for 1..32;
    $db{$key} = $val;
}

# this doesn't delete everything from the database!
keys(%db); # reset the iterator
while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db)) {
    delete $db{$key};
}

foreach (keys(%db)) {
    print("\$db{$_} = $db{$_}\n");
}

untie(%db);
```

When I run it, 4 (or sometimes 5) of the 10 records aren't deleted:

```
$db{4a8e5792e0} = 7a4d078a3f0f3cba750cb395fcc3343d
$db{d28e8cb226} = 17af1122f0b94113416693b1c4165954
$db{a3ae4e2e24} = 3c15270cf16601722bd8106b1727dbc2
$db{886c469eb4} = f1496f83f7866d09c9e28aae8e1b62e6
$db{2c53ebd993} = facfe8228240878aac825de4d97ca22b
```

If I run the script on a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) system, then it always works (all records deleted).

If I switch to a `foreach` loop over the keys, then it works on both NetBSD and Linux:

```
# this always works
foreach (keys(%db)) {
    delete $db{$_};
}
```

### What the Documentation Says

I haven't been able to find anything that clearly says that deleting while iterating via `each` doesn't always work.

Here's what I have been able to find:

- The [documentation for `foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) says:

  > `foreach` probably won't do what you expect if VAR is a tied or other special variable.

  I'm not sure what is meant by this, but oddly the `foreach` case is where it *does* work.
- The [documentation for `each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) says:

  > Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, with the exception that the most recent key returned by `each` or `keys` may be deleted without changing the order.

  To me this implies that it's safe to `delete` the current entry while iterating.
- The [documentation for `DB_File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB_File.html) doesn't mention deletion while iterating.

### Questions

Is this problem:

- caused by a bug in [NetBSD's Berkeley DB implementation](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/db/?only_with_tag=netbsd-6-1-RELEASE)?
- caused by a bug in DB_File?
- a known limitation of `each`?
- a known limitation of tied hashes?
- a known limitation of DB_File tied hashes?

Why does `foreach` on the keys work when `each` doesn't?

Comment: "To me this implies that it's safe to `delete` the current entry while iterating." For a hash, yes. But you don't have a hash here. Perl's docs cannot make claims as to what DB_File does or doesn't support.

Comment: @ikegami:  OK, so that rules out "a known limitation of `each`".  Right?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch it that the behavior is a limitation of tied hashes. There seems to be no guarantee that DB_File does not rehash when deleting the most recently fetched key.

You also asked about the difference between

```
while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db)) {
    delete $db{$key};
}
```

and

```
foreach (keys(%db)) {
    delete $db{$_};
}
```

.

In the first case you are meddling with the tied hash while iterating over the tied hash. So there is an opportunity that the iterator will not reach all keys.

In the second case you are first iterating over the tied hash in order to get the complete list of keys. When looping over the complete list you are guaranteed to delete all entries.

Comment: Oh, I was under the mistaken impression that `keys()` emitted a Python-like "generator" for efficient iteration over very large (possibly tied) hashes.  That's good to know, thank you!

Comment: Assuming it is possible to write a C program using NetBSD's Berkeley DB implementation that can delete while iterating without invalidating the iterator, then it should be possible to write DB_File to behave similarly.  So it sounds to me like this is a combination of things: (1) tying leaves the behavior up to the implementation (the implementation is allowed to behave nicely or horribly) and (2) either the implementation of DB_File isn't using the DB interface optimally or the NetBSD DB implementation makes it impossible to safely delete while iterating (it'd be nice to know which).